# Can't you Shecht on Yom Tov?

Tags: shabbat, maseches-shabbos, muktzeh

In [Tractate Beitza Perek Baiz Mishnah Ches](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Beitzah.2.8-9?lang=he&lookup=%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B0%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B8%D7%94%20%D7%93%D6%B0%D7%91%D6%B8%D7%A8%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%A8%D6%B7%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%99%20%D7%90%D6%B6%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%A2%D6%B8%D7%96%D6%B8%D7%A8%20%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B6%D7%9F%20%D7%A2%D6%B2%D7%96%D6%B7%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%99%D6%B8%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D6%B7%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%A8%2C%20%D7%95%D6%B7%D7%97%D6%B2%D7%9B%D6%B8%D7%9E%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%90%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%A1%D6%B0%D7%A8%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%9F.%20%D7%A4%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%A8%D6%B8%D7%AA%D7%95%D6%B9%20%D7%99%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%A6%D6%B0%D7%90%D6%B8%D7%94%20%D7%91%D6%B4%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%A6%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%A2%D6%B8%D7%94%20%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B6%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B5%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%A7%D6%B7%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%A0%D6%B6%D7%99%D7%94%D6%B8%2C%20%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%9E%D6%B0%D7%A7%D6%B8%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%93%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%90%D6%B6%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D6%B7%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%94%D6%B5%D7%9E%D6%B8%D7%94%20%D7%91%D6%B0%D7%99%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%9D%20%D7%98%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%91%2C%20%D7%95%D6%B0%D7%A9%D7%81%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%97%D6%B2%D7%A7%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%90%D6%B6%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D6%B7%D7%A4%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%A4%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%9C%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%A8%D6%B5%D7%97%D6%B7%D7%99%D6%B4%D7%9D%20%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B6%D7%9C%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%94%D6%B6%D7%9D.%20%D7%A8%D6%B7%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%99%20%D7%99%D6%B0%D7%94%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%93%D6%B8%D7%94%20%D7%90%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%9E%D6%B5%D7%A8%2C%20%D7%90%D6%B5%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%9E%D6%B0%D7%A7%D6%B8%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%93%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%90%D6%B6%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D6%B7%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%94%D6%B5%D7%9E%D6%B8%D7%94%20%D7%91%D6%B0%D7%99%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%9D%20%D7%98%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%91%2C%20%D7%9E%D6%B4%D7%A4%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%A0%D6%B5%D7%99%20%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B6%D7%A2%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%A9%D7%82%D6%B6%D7%94%20%D7%97%D6%B7%D7%91%D6%BC%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%A8%D6%B8%D7%94%2C%20%D7%90%D6%B2%D7%91%D6%B8%D7%9C%20%D7%9E%D6%B0%D7%A7%D6%B7%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%A6%D6%B0%D7%A4%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%9F.%20%D7%95%D6%B7%D7%97%D6%B2%D7%9B%D6%B8%D7%9E%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%90%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%9E%D6%B0%D7%A8%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%9D%2C%20%D7%90%D6%B5%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%9E%D6%B0%D7%A7%D6%B8%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%93%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%9F%2C%20%D7%90%D6%B7%D7%A3%20%D7%9C%D6%B9%D7%90%20%D7%9E%D6%B0%D7%A7%D6%B7%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%A6%D6%B0%D7%A4%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%9F%3A&with=Lexicon&lang2=he) it brings down a Machlokes between the Chachamim & Reb Elazar Ben Azaryah:

"Can you scratch or scrape the body of an animal with a metal comb on Yom Tov?"

Chachamim say "no", while Reb Elazar Ben Azaryah says "yes".

Rashi says in Tractate Shabbos 107 - this is because it will make the animal bleed, which is prohibited under the *melacha* of slaughtering.

But aren't you able to slaughter on Yom Tov - because it is food preparation?

Comment: Yes, but only *ochel nefesh*

Comment: Please don't shout.

Comment: See Tosfos on Shabbos 95a d"h והרודה that wants to make a related point; that boneh should be muttar on Yom Tov since megaben (a tolda of boneh) is muttar on Yom Tov min haTorah. Seemingly, both the Tosfos over there and your question should be taluy on whether an av melacha and all its toldos are jointly made muttar by the ochel nefesh-heiter, or if each tolda is treated separately.

Comment: "under the melacha of slaughtering."... Is that what Rashi says?

Answer (score 0):

See the sugya on Beitzah Daf 21 where excluded from the permission to do Melchos of food on Yom Tov is doing those melachos for a Goy or animal.

In the words of the (שו"ע הרב (ריש סימן תקיב

> כל מלאכות אוכל נפש לא הותרו אלא לצורך אכילת ישראל אבל לא לצורך אכילת
> נכרי ולא לצורך אכילת בהמה שנאמר הוא לבדו יעשה לכם לכם ולא לנכרים לכם
> ולא לבהמה.

See ביאור הלכה ריש סימן תקיב for a discussion if the prohibition stems from the Torah or Rabanun according to Rashi:

> וכן מצאתי אח"כ בשמ"ק שכתב דאף לדעת רש"י [וכן לדעת הרמב"ם העומד בשיטתו] דס"ל לענין הוצאה דאמרינן מתוך והותרה לגמרי אף שלא לצורך כלל מ"מ לצורך עו"ג גלתה לן התורה מקרא דלכם דגרע טפי ואסור מן התורה